# Bind RxSwift observable result to another observables

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I have an observable that manages an object called Profile:

```swift
class Profile {
    let name. : String
    let surname : String
    let avatar: String?
}
```

```swift
Observable<Profile>
```

This observable is binded to view model, who has a at the same time an observable property called

```swift
var initialMarks:Observable<String>
```

That are the initial letters of name and surname properties. This initial letters are shown in case avatar property is nil.

I have a function that returns initial letters in a string:

```swift
func initialLetters(first:String, second: String) -> String
```

How can I achieve this by using RxSwift any operators, to:

1. Access avatar property.
2. Check if it is nil.
3. if it is nil, call function initialLetters.
4. Bind function initialLetters to observable initialLetters.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a simple mapping...

Here it is as it's own view model.

```
func initialMarks(for profile: Observable<Profile>) -> Observable<String> {
    return profile
        .compactMap { profile in
            if profile.avatar == nil {
                return initialLetters(first: profile.name, second: profile.surname)
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
}
```

If you want to embed it in a view model struct/class you could do something like:

```
struct ViewModel {
    let profile: Observable<Profile>

    var initialMarks: Observable<String> {
        return profile
            .map { profile in
                if profile.avatar == nil {
                    return initialLetters(first: profile.name, second: profile.surname)
                }
                else {
                    return ""
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Also the two implementations above are subtly different depending on what you want... In the first one, it only emits initials when the avatar is nil, the second one emits an empty string when the avatar exists or initials when the avatar in nil.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example you need to use a [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html), so you can bind your stream `initialMarksSubject` and observe to it as `Observable`

**Setup**

```
private var initialMarksSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

private func observeInitialMarks() {
    profileObservable
        .filter { $0.avatar == nil } // only take elements that have a nil avatar
        .map { self.initialLetters(first: $0.name, second: $0.surname) } // transform profile to initialLetters of type String
        .bind(to: initialMarksSubject) // bind the stream to your subject
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

var initialMarks: Observable<String> {
    return initialMarksSubject.asObservable()
}
```

**Explanation**

Calling `observeInitialMarks()` would:

1. Subscribe to `profileObservable`
2. Accept only profiles that have no `avatar`
3. Transform the profile to `initialLetters`
4. Bind the events to `initialMarksSubject`

Subscribing to `initialMarks` would return the information that you need to display for your UI

**Usage to your UI Component**

```
viewModel.initialMarks
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .bind(to: profileLabel.rx.text)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: This is way too complex for what was asked.

Comment: In general, if you are reaching for a `Subject` in a view model, you are probably doing something wrong. View models are supposed to be fully reactive. (There are exceptions, but they are rare and this isn't one of them.)

Comment: This is what exactly what the OP asked, you can optimize in top of this of course, but I presumed the OP also wants to learn something to match his requirements. As for _In general, if you are reaching for a Subject, you are probably doing something wrong._, this statement cannot get worse...

Comment: _View models are supposed to be fully reactive_ normally you would try to reach this state, if all the services that the `ViewModel` uses, of course. But in the OP state I hardly think the state is what you are aiming for, thus the question how to make it reactive. Please provide a more detailed answer, before you try to "educate" (which I wouldn't call so).